# Contar duas vezes o número de registros de uma coluna para valores diferentes usando a função COUNT(*) em uma única query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu preciso contar a quantidade de acessos e curtidas por usuário para diferentes tipos de conteúdo.

SCHEMA:

```
secao
+--+--------+
|id| nome   |
+-----------+
|01| Vídeo  |
|02| Audio  |
|03| Imagem |
|04| Leitura|
+-----------+
```

```
tipo_midia
+--+----------+--------+
|id| id_secao | tipo   |
+--+----------+--------+
|01| 03       | Vídeo  |
|02| 02       | Audio  |
|03| 04       | Imagem |
|04| 01       | PDF    |
+--+----------+--------+
```

```
midia
+--+---------------+----------+
|id| id_tipo_midia | titulo   |
+--+---------------+----------+
|01| 02            | audio_01 |
|02| 01            | video_03 |
|03| 03            | imagem_02|
|04| 02            | audio_02 |     
|05| 01            | video_04 |   
|06| 04            | pdf_01   |
+--+---------------+----------+
```

```
users
+--+---------+---------+
|id| nome    | email   |
+--+---------+---------+
|01| user_01 | email_01| 
|02| user_02 | email_02|
|03| user_03 | email_03|
|04| user_04 | email_04|
+--+----------+--------+
```

```
registro
+-------+---------+------+----------+
|id_user|id_midia | acao |data_acao |
+-------+---------+------+----------+
|01     | 01      | 1    |2019-07-27|
|01     | 01      | 1    |2019-07-27|
|01     | 02      | 2    |2019-07-27|
|02     | 01      | 1    |2019-07-27|
|03     | 03      | 2    |2019-07-27|
|03     | 03      | 1    |2019-07-27|
|02     | 04      | 1    |2019-07-27|
|01     | 06      | 2    |2019-07-27|
+-------+---------+------+----------+
```

Na tabela `registro`, a coluna `acao` quando for `1` significa `acesso` e quando for `2` significa `curtida`.

Minha query:

```
SELECT U.nome AS usuario, U.email, M.titulo AS _midia, T.tipo, S.nome AS _secao, 
COUNT(A.`type`=1) AS acessos, COUNT(A.`type`=2) AS curtidas, MAX(A.`data`) ultima_data 
FROM registro A
INNER JOIN user U ON (A.id_user = U.id)
INNER JOIN midia M ON (A.id_midia = M.id)
INNER JOIN tipo_midia T ON (M.id_tipo_midia = T.id)
INNER JOIN secao S ON (T.id_secao = S.id)
GROUP BY 1, 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize `CASE`:

```
SELECT U.nome AS usuario, U.email, M.titulo AS _midia, T.tipo, S.nome AS _secao, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN A.`type` = 1 THEN 1 END) AS acessos, COUNT(CASE WHEN A.`type` = 2 THEN 1 END) AS curtidas, MAX(A.`data`) ultima_data 
FROM registro A
INNER JOIN user U ON (A.id_user = U.id)
INNER JOIN midia M ON (A.id_midia = M.id)
INNER JOIN tipo_midia T ON (M.id_tipo_midia = T.id)
INNER JOIN secao S ON (T.id_secao = S.id)
GROUP BY 1, 3
```